# Query para retornar quantidade minima de valores "diferentes"

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Tenho uma tabela chamada `clientes` e essa tabela tem uma coluna `status` que pode ter +/- 3 tipos `(novo, cancelado, pendente...)`

preciso exibir uma quantidade de informações separadas por `status`, e ao invés de fazer isso com 3 queries, `sendo` um where para cada status, gostaria de saber se é possível numa só query retornar os 3 status com uma quantidade minima de cada um deles:

Exemplo atual:

```
Cliente::where('status', 'novo')->take(20)->get();
Cliente::where('status', 'cancelado')->take(20)->get();
Cliente::where('status', 'pendente')->take(20)->get();
```

é possível, em uma só query, retornar 20 resultados para cada status diferente?

Comment: Não tem como você construir o que deseja da maneira que está propondo, entenda que status é uma relação de um para um e reside noutra tabela.

Entretanto você pode criar de maneira correta, note que o que você deseja fazer é olhar sob o ponto de vista do STATUS e não do cliente, logo você será obrigado a usar o modelo STATUS e não cliente para montar a consulta.

Comment: na verdade, o status está na mesma tabela, é só uma tabela

Comment: Alguma resposta consegui seu problema???

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar um "group by", para isso ficaria algo assim:

```
Cliente::groupBy('status')->select('status', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))->get();
```

Lembre-se de usar a namespace DB

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas aí viriam mais do que 20, viriam todos

Answer (score 0):

Sim, com o comando [union](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#unions), criando até a [query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries) sem compilar as [sql](/questions/tagged/sql), exemplo:

```
$a = Cliente::where('status', 'novo')->take(20);
$b = Cliente::where('status', 'cancelado')->take(20);
$c = Cliente::where('status', 'pendente')->take(20);
```

e depois dessas 3 linhas que ainda não forma executadas no banco faça a ligação da seguinte forma:

```
$result = $a->union($b)->union($c)->get();
```

e vale lembrar que esse método do [eloquent](/questions/tagged/eloquent) ORM tem mais ou menos essa [sql](/questions/tagged/sql):

```
SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE status = 'novo' limit 20
UNION
SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE status = 'cancelado' limit 20
UNION
SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE status = 'pendente' limit 20
```

ou seja, uma única [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) é enviada e retornar os dados que é necessário mediante as condições.